# Page not displaying properly

Tags: angularjs

I'm following along in a tutorial in Brad Green's newest publication for Angular JS and am having problems getting a shopping cart page to display correctly. Is there anything I would need to change in the code that I've got to remedy this?

[image]

**shopping-cart.html**

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
        <title>Your Shopping Cart</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller='CartController'>
        <h1>Your Order</h1>
        <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
                <span>{{item.title}}</span>
                <input ng-model='item.quantity'>
                <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
                <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
                <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="cartcontroller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**cartcontroller.js**

```
function CartController($scope) {
        $scope.items = [
                {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
                {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
                {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
        ];

        $scope.remove = function(index) {
                $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this at the top of your controller.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Here is a working demo:  http://plnkr.co/edit/ZW0iyP636DXoIac3yLdl?p=preview

That line will define your app and you'd include any other dependencies like angular ui or angular bootstrap so that they would be available to your app.  Here is another example that includes another module as a dependency in this case a google map module:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ["google-maps"]);  // http://plnkr.co/edit/5mdRdrOLRkW6PuLuH3Cv?p=catalogue
```

Comment: That did it thank you for the snippet of code and the explanation. :)